# Calculating Screen Coordinates from +/- Cartesian Input Values

Tags: c#, math, cartesian-product

I have two integer values that need to be converted into screen co-ordinates (doubles) in both directions. Score values (-50 to 50) to screen (as in the example code below, a screen 300 x 300 points/pixels) and screen to score value. I have drawn up a visual example:

[image]

I have also created a small console application program to test out the calculations which obviously doesn't work at all at the moment and I'm really struggling with the maths.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double screenWidth = 300;
        double screenHeight = 300;

        double MaxX = 50;
        double MinX = -50;

        double MaxY = 50;
        double MinY = -50;

        // x = 150
        // y = 150
        // given these inputs
        CalcScoreToScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0);

        // x = 300
        // y = 0
        // given these inputs
        CalcScoreToScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight, 50, 0);

        // x = 225
        // y = 225
        // given these inputs
        CalcScoreToScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight, 25, -25);

        // x = 75
        // y = 75
        // given these inputs
        CalcScoreToScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight, -25, 25);

        // x = -25
        // y = 25
        // given these inputs
        CalcScreenToScore(screenWidth, screenHeight, 75, 75);

        // x = 25
        // y = -25
        // given these inputs
        CalcScreenToScore(screenWidth, screenHeight, 225, 225);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CalcScoreToScreen(double screenWidth, double screenHeight, int scoreX, int scoreY)
    {
        var screenX = scoreX + screenWidth / 2;

        var screenY = scoreY + screenHeight / 2;

        Console.WriteLine("Screen X: {0} - Score: {1}", screenX, scoreX);
        Console.WriteLine("Screen Y: {0} - Score: {1}", screenY, scoreY);
    }

    private static void CalcScreenToScore(double screenWidth, double screenHeight, double screenX, double screenY)
    {
        int scoreX = Convert.ToInt32(screenX + screenWidth / 2);
        int scoreY = Convert.ToInt32(screenY + screenHeight / 2);

        Console.WriteLine("Score X: {0} - Screen X: {1}", scoreX, screenX);
        Console.WriteLine("Score Y: {0} - Screen Y: {1}", scoreY, screenY);
    }
}
```

Comment: "which obviously doesn't work at all at the moment" <--- obviously?  I think you're going to have to enlighten us.  What *exactly* is not working right?  If you're having trouble with the mathematics, and not the programming, this might not be the right place for this question (try math stack exchange).

Comment: @MsYvette, yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @roryap I'm really not sure what I can add to this, there are all the methods and inputs and expected outputs defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void CalcScoreToScreen(double screenWidth, double screenHeight, int scoreX, int scoreY, double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY)
{
    var screenX = (scoreX - minX)/(maxX-minX)*screenWidth;
    var screenY = screenHeight - (scoreY - minY)/(maxY-minY)*screenHeight;

    Console.WriteLine("Screen X: {0} - Score: {1}", screenX, scoreX);
    Console.WriteLine("Screen Y: {0} - Score: {1}", screenY, scoreY);
}

private static void CalcScreenToScore(double screenWidth, double screenHeight, double screenX, double screenY, double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY)
{
    int scoreX = Convert.ToInt32(minX + (maxX-minX)*screenX/screenWidth );
    int scoreY = Convert.ToInt32(minY + (maxY-minY)*(screenHeight - screenY)/screenHeight );

    Console.WriteLine("Score X: {0} - Screen X: {1}", scoreX, screenX);
    Console.WriteLine("Score Y: {0} - Screen Y: {1}", scoreY, screenY);
}
```

Comment: This is almost right, the problem is one calculation is off - Screen Y: 75 - Score: -25, this should result in a score of 25.

Comment: Oh right your Y axis have opposite directions. I will update my answer now.

Comment: Give it another try.

Comment: I know this is asking a bit more but I'm looking at the code to try and understand it better.  What is the order or precedence in this - screenHeight - (scoreY - minY)/(maxY-minY)*screenHeight; I'm assuming that associativity is coming into play somewhere?

Comment: `(scoreY - minY)/(maxY-minY) `- that will be calculated first. You can look at it as percent. How much of height is used. Then we multiply it by `screenHeight` to convert % to actual Y coordinate. And at the end we do `screenHeight - Y` to get flipped value as axis are opposite.

Comment: Many, many thanks.  Times like this reminds me how much I don't know I thought I did!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this functions to your code to convert the values of marks to positions on the screen.

This is to calculate your score to screen.

Using screenheight as max screen height and screenwidth as max screen width that you are using to display your marks graphically. You can then interchange the max/min value of your marks or 50 to be any variable, as I have taken the screen width/height variable of 300 and made it a variable.

Values extend across 100: -50 to 50.
For X:
so negative values cover first 50% of screen, positive values second 50%

```
if(Xvalue == 0)
    screenXPos = Screenwidth/2;

else if(Xvalue < 0)
    screenXPos = Screenwidth/2 + Screenwidth/2*Xvalue/50; // this will be negative so subtract from half screenwidth.

else
    screenXPos = Screenwidth*Xvalue/50;
```

For Y:

Negative values are from max screenheight to half screenheight positive value are from half screenheight to zero.

```
if(Yvalue == 0)
    screenYPos = Screenheight/2;

else if(Yvalue < 0)
    screenYPos = screenheight/2 -Screenheight/2*Yvalue/50; // don't want negative value for screen position.

else
    screenYPos = screenheight/2*Yvalue/50;
```

Comment: What if minX: -10 and maxX: 77? You'll probably need to update all your formulas/conditions when those are changed.

Comment: @MsYvette the selected answer by serhiyb works brilliantly and the format of the code is much more succinct.